# Uninstalling a plugin from Craft control panel

Tags: plugins, control-panel, uninstall

I'm new to Craft CMS and I'm having trouble figuring out how to uninstall a plugin.  Specifically, it's the "Redactor Custom Styles" plugin.

I gather from searching (please correct me if I'm wrong) that I need to first uninstall it from within the Craft control panel, and then use composer to remove it i.e. `composer remove vendor/plugin-handle`.  I'm stuck on the first part of that.

Within my control panel, I can't seem to find a list of installed plugins anywhere. The only way I can even see that Redactor Custom Styles plugin is installed is by going to the Plugin Store, searching for it again as if I was going to install it, clicking the result, and then I see a checkmark and "Installed".  However, there's no option to uninstall it.

I must be missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Plugins
There you will find a pulldown for each plugin with an uninstall option.

Comment: I definitely missed that, thank you!